# calculating basic formula if and or

Tags: excel

**Sheet Participants:**

[image]

**Sheet Actual Results:**

[image]

What I am trying to do is for the Participants sheet to look up the actual results sheet

My formula to display the outcome (this doesn't work correctly)

```
=IF(AND(B2='Actual Results'!B1,
        C2='Actual Results'!C1),
    "CORRECT SCORE & RESULT",
    IF(AND('Actual Results'!B1>'Actual Results'!C1,
           Participants!B2>Participants!C2),
       "CORRECT RESULT",
       "INCORRECT RESULT"))
```

The reason its not working 100% is because when the greater than comparisons in the formula come into play and the team in column D in actual results has more goals then its not working. If I change the greater thans to less thans, then it works, but this won’t be consistent.

Look up score in B and C (Participants).

IF Scoreline is correct - 5 points

If result is correct but not scoreline – 2 points

If winner is not correct - Minus 1 point

**Example:**

[image]

If actual was 0-0 and prediction is 0-0  then 5 points… if prediction is 1-1 , then 2 points still. Works the same for an actual result draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
AND('Actual Results'!B1>'Actual Results'!C1,
       Participants!B2>Participants!C2)
```

to

```
OR(AND('Actual Results'!B1>'Actual Results'!C1,
       Participants!B2>Participants!C2),
   AND('Actual Results'!B1<'Actual Results'!C1,
       Participants!B2<Participants!C2),
   AND('Actual Results'!B1='Actual Results'!C1,
       Participants!B2=Participants!C2))
```